# Ansible "Yes" and "No" possibilites for installation

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

is possible to prompt user with "Yes" and "No" question? I am sure there it is, but I need it to install package on "yes" answer and with "no" just skip package. How to effectively do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to ask a user a question while running a playbook.
Use [`vars_prompt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "What is your username?"
      private: no

    - name: password
      prompt: "What is your password?"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'Logging in as {{ username }}'
```

An example with boolean:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:
    - name: install_apache
      prompt: "Install Apache?"
      private: no

  tasks:
    - apt:
        name: apache2
        state: present
      when: install_apache
```

Depending on use-case for this specific example, it might be that a [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) with specific defined variable is a better solution.

I disagree that **every-time** playbook should **not** run interactively. An example with installing a package might not be so relevant, because it is strictly associated with *[Infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code)*, approach.

We have a set of other [use-cases](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases):

- Automate daily tasks.
- Load testing preparation.
- Continous Integration / Continous Deployment.
- [...]

Comment: Yeah but I have 3 differend packages, which I want user to ask if he wants them when playing the playbook..

Answer (score 2):

Ansible playbooks should run non-interactively.

You want to use a variable for this kind of decision.

Comment: Yeah but I have 3 differend packages, which I want user to ask if he wants them when playing the playbook..

Comment: Then document variable names that control installing these things, and hint to new users which var files an override would go.  Personally, I do not like interactive Ansible prompts at all.